# If $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the roots of $x^{3}+x^{2}-2 x+1=0$ find the value of the following matrix

Tags: matrices

If $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the roots of $x^{3}+x^{2}-2 x+1=0$, then find the value of

$\Delta=\left|\begin{array}{ccc}\gamma^{2} & \beta^{2} & 2 \beta \gamma-\alpha^{2} \\ 2 \alpha \gamma-\beta^{2} & \alpha^{2} & \gamma^{2} \\ \alpha^{2} & 2 \alpha \beta-\gamma^{2} & \beta^{2}\end{array}\right|$

Calculating the determinant by expanding it doesn't seem like the right way. I am also not able to do row operations which lead me somewhere. If I make $R1  = R1 + R2 + R3$ it creates terms like $(\alpha + \beta)^2 - \gamma^2$ and so on but not able to do anything with this.

How should I proceed to calculate this ?

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5Bc%5E2+%2C+b%5E2+%2C+2+b+c-a%5E2+%5D%2C%5B+2+a+c-b%5E2+%2C+a%5E2+%2C+c%5E2+%5D%2C%5B+a%5E2+%2C+2+a+b-c%5E2+%2C+b%5E2%5D%5D) can help with the determinant. You still need to use $x^{3}+x^{2}-2 x+1=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us use $a,b,c$ as roots of the cubic, then use row to row multiplication of two simple determinant to get:
$$D=\begin{vmatrix}c^2 & b^2 & 2bc-a^2 \\ 2ac-b^2 & a^2 & c^2 \\ a^2 & 2ab-c^2 & b^2 \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} a & b & c \\ b & c &a \\c & a& b \end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix} -b & a & c \\ -c & b & a\\ -a & c & b\end{vmatrix}=(a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc)^2,$$
Since, $$a+b+c=-1,ab+bc+ca=-2, abc=-1 \implies a^2+b^2+c^2=5, a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=
(a+b+c)[a^2+b^2+c^2-(ab+bc+ca)]=-7.$$ Hence $D=49.$

Edit: Yes @ashish you are right. I have edited now.

Comment: You sure it's not $\begin{vmatrix} a & b & c \\ b & c &a \\c & a& b \end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix} -b & a & c \\ -c & b & a  \\ -a & c & b\end{vmatrix}$ what you meant ?

Comment: +1, great one! How did you get this though I couldn't have thought of this at all! Is it just practice or are there any resources which can help me in these type of problems?

Comment: When terms of a determinant are quadratic then it can be seen as a product of two determinants or as an adjoint of as simple determinant.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding the determinant isn't actually so bad. Using $abc$ instead of $\alpha \beta\gamma$ for convenience, you get
$$
\Delta = (abc)^2 + (abc)^2 + (2bc - a^2)(2ac-b^2)(2ab-c^2) -a^4(2bc-a^2)- b^4(2ac-b^2) -c^4(2ab-c^2) = (3abc)^2 - 6abc(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) +2(a^3b^3 + b^3c^3+a^3c^3) + a^6 + b^6 + c^6 = (a^3+b^3+c^3 - 3abc)^2
$$
The coefficients of the cubic can be expressed in terms of [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Examples) of the roots, so we want to express this quantity in terms of those. It's not too hard to figure out $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 -3abc = (a+b+c)^3 - 3(a+b+c)(ab + bc + ac)$, so we have
$$
\Delta = [(a+b+c)^3 - 3(a+b+c)(ab + bc + ac)]^2 = [(-1)^3 - 3(-1)(-2)]^2 = 49
$$

Comment: The hard part is factoring the determinant.

Comment: [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) are relevant to compute $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$.

Comment: Factorizing the denominator and handling these terms would definitely increase the scope of making errors, which is why I was curious if there were any solutions using operations that make life easier. This isn't as bad as I thought though

Answer (score 1):

> If $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the roots of $x^3+x^2-2x+1=0$ find the value of
> \begin{align}\Delta&=\left|\begin{array}{ccc}\gamma^{2} & \beta^{2} & 2 \beta \gamma-\alpha^{2} \\ 2 \alpha \gamma-\beta^{2} & \alpha^{2} & \gamma^{2} \\ \alpha^{2} & 2 \alpha \beta-\gamma^{2} & \beta^{2}\end{array}\right|\end{align}

The expression of the determinant can be organized as follows:

\begin{align} 
\Delta&=
9e_3^2
-6e_3 p_3
+p_3^2
,
\end{align}

where
\begin{align} 
e_3&=\alpha\beta\gamma
,\\
p_3&=\gamma^3+\beta^3+\alpha^3
.
\end{align}

We are given that
\begin{align} 
p_1=e_1=\gamma+\beta+\alpha&=-1
,\\
e_2=\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma+\beta\alpha&=-2
,\\
e_3=\alpha\beta\gamma&=-1
,\\
e_k&=0\quad\text{for }\quad k>3
\end{align}

and using [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities),
we have

\begin{align} 
p_1=e_1&=-1
,\\
e_3&=-1
,\\
p_3&=-10
.
\end{align}

hence the answer is

\begin{align} 
\Delta&=9\cdot(-1)^2-6\cdot(-1)\cdot(-10)+(-10)^2
=49
.
\end{align}

Comment: $\Delta=9e_3^2-6e_3 p_3+p_6+p_6^2$ This is wrong.

Comment: @eyeballfrog: Of course, thanks. Should be 
$9e_3^2-6e_3 p_3+p_3^2$. The copy/paste typo fixed.